# Django view to display objects by user to visitor

Tags: python, django, view

I created an app that allows registered users to create products using a form.  Each registered user has a profile page displaying their products that only they can see when logged in.  I want to create a view that will allow an unregistered user to view products by any user by clicking on a username. How do I do that?

Here's the product form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'product_type', 'price', 'image', 'image_url']
        labels = {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'url': 'Product URL',
            'product_type': 'Product Type',
            'description': 'Product Description',
            'image': 'Product Image',
            'image_url': 'Product Image URL',
            'price': 'Product Price'
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}),
        }
```

The product views are simple:

```
    def products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'products.html', {'products': products, 'form':form})


def post_product(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ProductForm(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            product = form.save(commit = False)
            product.user = request.user
            product.likes = 0
            product.save()
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products')
```

Let me know if I need to show anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    paginate_by = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.request.GET.get('username',None)
        user = None
        if username:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
                pass
        if user:
            return Product.objects.filter(user=user)
        return Product.objects.none()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^product/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

access page like `www.example.com/product?username=testuser`

according to your edit:

```
def products(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username',None)
    user = None
    if username:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            pass
    if user:
        return Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()
    form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'products.html', {'products': products, 'form':form})
```

Comment: I had to add from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView - now I get an error - TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ContextMixin, ListView

Comment: you can use method i update according to your function.

Comment: I did - and I appreciate the help - still getting the TypeError though.  I'm researching it also.  I'm guessing I need a url pattern for this too.

Comment: I already have this for the products page:  url(r'^products/$', views.products, name = 'products'), - not sure what to add - would a url pattern fix the TypeError?

Comment: post the details of your TypeError and update it in your question

Comment: Per above - here it is again:  class ProductListView(ContextMixin, ListView):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ContextMixin, ListView

Comment: you use class base view `ProductListView` or `def products(request)`,which one?

Comment: Ah - I have both - didn't realize it was one or the other -  removed ProductListView

Comment: i find the error,change `class ProductListView(ContextMixin, ListView): `to `class ProductListView(ListView):`

Comment: That resolved the issue - using this url brings up the page but no products are listed:  product/?username=steveshead

Comment: I'm only offering ideas,the details is on your own

Comment: Scratch that - I changed the loop and it's working now - thanks for the assist.

Comment: Yep - I've marked your answer as correct and added a vote - thanks again.

Comment: it's my pleasure